# Get position of path geometry relative to it's parent

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, shapes, pathgeometry

My application adds path shapes into a grid (via code-behind), that kind of resembles this:

```
<Path Data='M0,161 L200,161 L200,1 L130,1 L130,21 L150,21 L150,41 L180,41 L180,136 L20,136 L20,41 L50,41 L50,21 L70,21 L70,6 L130,6 L130,1 L0,1 z'/>
```

And these paths are then inside a grid, itself inside a viewbox. How can I get the position of the Path relative to the grid, when it's starting point isn't M0,0? I've tried using stuff like Canvas.GetLeft(path)/Canvas.GetTop(path) but it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Try to get the [`Bounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.geometry.bounds.aspx) of the Path's `Data`, probably scaled by the Viewbox scale.

Comment: For anyone reading, this works great.